# Automatically dial a phone number

Tags: html, anchor

I have a web page where I have a button. I need to automatically dial a phone number on the click of the button. It needs to be done in HTML.

I need to do it on the onclick event of the button.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On mobile devices, there are protocol handlers to launch the phone. Depending on the security, some will dial it, or others will bring on the phone application with the number already there.

```
<a href="tel:+15555555555">Call me at +1 (555) 555-5555</a>
```

Comment: is it possible to configure the settings (in the project or on the phone) to allow direct phone dialing without launching the default phone dialer? I have added the CALL_PHONE right but still it doesn't make the call directly.

Comment: It's not only on mobile devices.  On my linux desktop, the Chrome browser automatically invokes Google Voice to make the call when I click on "tel:" hrefs.

Answer (score 4):

I've used this in the past for mobile apps:

```
<button id="call">Call</button>

<script>
    $("#call").on('click', function() {
        var link = "tel:18003334444";
        window.location.href = link;
    });
</script>
```

This, of course, uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think this is possible in HTML... Have you done any research on Java or PHP? a quick google reveals a [grand central API](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/08/dial-a-phone-number-using-grand-central-and-php/), and [Java Phone](http://java.sun.com/products/javaphone/overview.html), But I don't know how much help they will be. Also, for future reference, it helps if you tell us what you want to do with this number, will you be connecting it to another phone number? To your computer? Etc.  Regardless, this is going to be a fairly complex project, and would be so even if you were comfortable with a real programming language. Your best approach would be to figure out your options and then come back to Stack overflow if you need help on choosing one. Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

I have to declare a commercial interest. I work for Cisco and we've developed a JavaScript SDK and browser plugin that enable you to do this, but only in a Cisco deployment. If you're interested, here's the link:-

http://developer.cisco.com/web/jabber-developer/jabber