# How to make a number in html to be clickable so that it will make a call automatically in HTL in AEM

Tags: javascript, aem, sightly

I have a line like this in my HTL

Contact: 89569441594

so on my web page if any user wants to call that number by clicking it.

Code:

```
<span class="number"><a href="${obj.number}">{obj.number}</a></span>
```

how can we use javascriprt to make it click on number to call automatically

Comment: This is a good question. Why is it like -2. I want to be able to do this as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505221/12894605

Answer (score 2):

HTL/Sightly is a server-side templating engine. That means it will render the values for `${obj.number}` when that page fragment is rendered on the server.

You seem to need something on client-side that is able to bind to the click event, make a call somewhere (using AJAX) and get the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span><a href="tel://89569441594" aria-atomic="true" data-type="link" title="89569441594">89569441594</a></span>
```

Use a phone number that way.